# Unexpected field binding behaviour in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've just come across some unexpected field binding behaviour in ReactJS and I'm just wondering if this is normal.  Suppose my component tree looks like the following.

```
<Parent>
    <Controls/>
    <TypeList/>
</Parent>
```

In the `Controls` component, I have some form elements, namely some `select` input fields with given names, ids and ref attributes.  For example I have a `select` where name, id and ref all are set to `bookMonth`.  These `select` elements have an `onChange` handler which calls a Redux action creator that fetches data from the server and updates the store.

In `TypeList` I have several `Link` instances (using React Router) where I set the `to` attribute to something like `/byType?type=${type}&bookMonth=${bookMonth}`.  The unexpected behaviour I've encountered is that `${bookMonth}` has automatically been bound to the value of the `select` in `Controls` without being defined anywhere else in `TypeList`.  The value is not coming from my Redux store.  I've merely placed `${bookMonth}` in my url and it was automatically bound.

So I'm just wondering if this is expected behaviour that I've never known about before.

Comment: anything red on console is not expected behavior..

Comment: I never said there was anything red in the console, but thanks for that input.  No errors are thrown.

Comment: Where is `bookMonth` defined then? It would throw an undefined error if you didn't define it.

Comment: That's exactly why I find it unexpected.  It isn't defined in the `TypeList` component, yet it's not throwing an undefined error.

Comment: The only time I get the undefined error on `bookMonth` is once I'm on the `byType` view and I press the browser back button.  But I would have expected an undefined error long before getting that far.

Comment: is your project built using modules (webpack / browserify) ? If not maybe something is leaking into the global namespace

Comment: Yes, I'm using Webpack.  I'll clarify my question by saying I'm not relying on this behaviour because it breaks my app elsewhere.  I just found it odd that the values were getting bound without me explicitly binding them.